# SparkPandasNotImplementedError: .iloc requires numeric slice or conditional boolean Index

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I keep getting the following error on Databricks:

> SparkPandasNotImplementedError: .iloc requires numeric slice or conditional boolean Index, got  You are trying to use pandas function .iloc[..., ...], use spark function select, where

this is my code:

```
import re 
import nltk
import heapq
corpus = []
for i in range(0, len(Y)):
    describe = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', Y.iloc[i, 0])
    describe = describe.lower()
    describe = describe.split()
    describe = ' '.join(describe)
    corpus.append(describe)
```

The code works fine in Spyder, but not in databricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same issue as yours successfully, as the code and figure below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import databricks.koalas as ks
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = ks.from_pandas(pdf)
print(pdf.iloc[0,0])
print(df.iloc[0,0])
```

[image]

Due to lack of the necessary description of your variable `Y`, I guess `Y` is a dataframe, but the differences are `pandas` dataframe on local Spyder, [`Koalas`](https://github.com/databricks/koalas) dataframe in databricks.

According to the Koalas document for [`databricks.koalas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.iloc.html), it does not support the operation `iloc(int, int)` for a Koalas dataframe.

[image]

So if you want to do some operation for the first column value of each row in databricks, there are two solutions as below.

1. Make sure `Y` is a pandas dataframe in the same script of your databricks.
2. `Y` must be a Koalas dataframe as you want, please try to the code as below.

   ```
   # Here, `Y` is a Koalas dataframe
   for row in Y.iterrows():
       describe = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', row[1][0])
       describe = describe.lower()
       describe = describe.split()
       describe = ' '.join(describe)
       corpus.append(describe)
   ```

   As you can see my sample code and result below, the function `iterrows` can help to get get the first column value of each row.

   [image]